# How to add credit card validation check to wordpress

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

Im working on a restaurant reservation website and I need to add a feature similar to one found on booking.com, that is once someone wants to make the reservation I would need them to leave us their credit card information for the restaurant they are booking a table at just in case if they are "no-show". But I need it to be an actual valid credit card, so the system should pull the information from somewhere and make sure it's a real credit card, is there a possibility to make such thing a reality?

Comment: There must be a way because some payment providers _(e.g **Stripe** and **Braintree**)_ will make live credit card validation checks.. **but** this is super specific and requires some very specific skills which means that this is super off-topic here.

Comment: Where should I ask for an answer for this question?

Comment: This is a frontend javascript question, WordPress questions should require knowledge of WordPress, perhaps stack overflow would be more useful "How do I validate a credit card number in javascript?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "valid credit card", you mean a valid credit card *number*, then that can be done automatically with JavaScript. You're looking for a Luhn algorithm implementation. Here's one I just found on GitHub: https://gist.github.com/DiegoSalazar/4075533

Otherwise, if you want to validate that it's an active credit card that can support a payment of a certain amount, you'll need to tie into a service like [Stripe](http://stripe.com/).

There are jQuery widgets for the Luhn stuff you could add, and doubtlessly WordPress plugins that'll offer Stripe integration.

Comment: Yes this is what I needed, will just have to test it out (Luhn algorithm). Do you know if I can check th CVC number with this as well? Thank you!

Comment: CVC? No, it purely checks if the credit card number is a valid one (like a valid email or valid phone number), the CVC and expiry date are unrelated data that is unique to the account and verified by the card company.